# how can i embed MozSwing with swing application for cross platform application

Tags: java, swing, mozilla

i know google is my friend ,, but i couldn't find any good easy tutorial on embedding mozswing 
into swing application , i like to avoid using it with SWT but is its more easier its ok .
can you please point me to some examples?

Answer (score 0):

I think your (and my) best bet is JavaFX 2.0 having have a WebView component.  I'd love to be proven wrong but I think mozswing is dead.

I find it unbelievable that nobody out here has done a native compile of Webkit and slapped a nice Java wrapper around it.  Hey, maybe it's out there already and we don't know how to find it.  Anyone care to add to this?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX's webview is good for normal rendering.
But if you're thinking about Flash and what not, it doesn't support this yet as of today.

[all future readers must judge this statement by the date/time it was made :) ]